# Angular 2 mode = "Observable" what does it do?

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular2-services

I am working on an Angular 2 project and I came across a tutorial that used something like this format. I am using an Observable to interact with a database and retrieve data and this is the component that is subscribing to the service where that is happening. The tutorial had

`mode = 'Observable';`

What exactly does this do? I can't seem to find much about it online. I can assume what it does, but is it necessary?

```
export class TaxRateLookupComponent {
  errorMessage: string;
  mode = 'Observable';
  taxRate: TaxRate[];

  constructor(
    private taxRateLookupService: TaxRateLookupService,
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}


  getTaxRate(search) {
    this.taxRateLookupService.getTaxRate(search)
                      .subscribe(
                        taxRate => this.taxRate = taxRate,
                        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }


}
```

Comment: it doesn't do anything

Comment: It's just a string variable with has 'Observable' as a value. Maybe it was used as some kind of documentation in tutorial.